# Function to allow using @ for error suppression

Tags: php, function, error-handling

I'm interested in how could I create my own function allowing it to be executed without error logging, but only if executed with `@` operator, like `@function();`?

Function:

```
public function query($sql, $id = false){
    $this->query_id = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    if(!$this->query_id){
        // I want to suppress this error call here...
        psyo::error("Error while executing query (sql: {$sql}).");
        return NULL;
    }else{
        $this->result = mysqli_store_result($this->connection);
        $this->affected = mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection);
        return $id ? $this->query_id : $this;
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm using my own error handling class, and it isn't operated with `error_log();` or so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#98895

Comment: If I call simply `query();`, `psyo::error();` is executed; if I call `@query();` it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Please be sure to also upvote [@Josh Davis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554862/function-to-allow-using-for-error-suppression/5554967#5554967) if you haven't already. He gave a similar, and very correct, answer as mine while I was still writing/testing mine. He deserves some love as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` operator is just shorthand for the following:

```
$oldReportingLevel = error_reporting();
error_reporting(0);
 // execute @'d code here
error_reporting($oldReportingLevel);
```

In other words, `@` temporarily sets the error reporting level to 0. While you can't check whether or not the current error reporting level is due to an `@` operator or not, you *can* check the current error reporting level, and bypass your own error handling if the level is 0.

What you probably want is this:

```
if (error_reporting() != 0) {
 psyo::error("Error while executing query (sql: {$sql}).");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a way to *know* for sure whether the @-operator was used to call a function, but you can use `error_reporting()` to test for the current level, which is 0 when the @-operator is being used.

```
function test()
{   
    var_dump(error_reporting());
}

test();
@test();
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>If I am understanding you right, you want a way to suppress your own errors from your class call. One way is to make a boolean variable in the class, `showErrors` and then in the `psyo::error` function, check that variable. If `showErrors` is true, display them, else do not display them but log them (or handle them however you want).</s>

If you mean that you want the @ to suppress your class errors that are passed to the error function, then I think your error function would need to "trigger errors". See [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/trigger_error) for more details on that.